# Does Enabling Enhanced Domains in Salesforce have any downstream effects to SFMC through MCC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization, enhanced-domains

Does enabling [Enhanced Domains](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_enhanced.htm&type=5) in Salesforce org have any impact to an existing connection through the Marketing Cloud Connector and data flowing into SFMC?

My gut is saying "no" as the managed package will still be the same but just seeing if anyone has any first-hand experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received an answer from SFMC support:

If the Enhanced Domain changes are made then the remote site setting will need to be updated via the [Setup Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_launch_setup_wizard.htm&type=5).

There are no other changes that would need to be done -- just updating the remote site settings. No other MC functionality should be affected.