# Is there any affect on SFMC URLs due to Salesforce implementing || ENHANCED DOMAINS

Tags: marketing-cloud, enhanced-domains

Thanks to @**Jackson Chen** for this [Does Enabling Enhanced Domains in Salesforce have any downstream effects to SFMC through MCC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391140/does-enabling-enhanced-domains-in-salesforce-have-any-downstream-effects-to-sfmc)

**SF help article** = https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394580&type=1

Dear Community mates,
please share highlights, and suggest any other changes or implications from this change.

Comment: Duplicate of [Does Enabling Enhanced Domains in Salesforce have any downstream effects to SFMC through MCC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391140/does-enabling-enhanced-domains-in-salesforce-have-any-downstream-effects-to-sfmc) , your question should be a comment over there.